# Why is it that the vector space of all derivations has the basis $\partial/\partial{x_1} \ldots \partial/\partial{x_n}$?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, manifolds

So I have seen stated that two definitions of tangent spaces (w.r.t manifolds) are equivalent.

But I am having some difficulty proving they are indeed equivalent. It looks like it boils down to me showing that if $A : C^{\infty}(M) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map such that $A(f\cdot g)= A(f)\cdot g(P) + A(g)\cdot f(P)$ then A is a (linear) sum of partial derivatives.

I've gone down the route of showing this is true on polynomials, but haven't managed to generalise to all of $C^{\infty}(M)$.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How is $P$ defined?

Comment: $P$ is just some point in some $C^{\infty}$ manifold $M$

Comment: And how is the dot-product defined?  As application of a differential operator?

Comment: $(f \cdot g)(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$

Comment: I haven't thought deeply about what lies behind "local coordinates".  But you can't you show that the partials with respect those coordinates behave like a dot-product.  I'm sorry that's really vague, it's probably what you are already trying.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to include local coordinates. If you can elaborate what you mean by this then that woul be helpful. The issue I have is not that the partial derivatives form a subspace. The problem I am having is showing they span the space.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. If $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ we have:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(a) + \int_0^1 \frac d {dt} f(a + t(x - a)) dt \\
&= f(a) + \sum_{k = 1}^n (x_k - a)\int_0^1 \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_k}(a + t(x - a)) dt \\
&= f(a) + \sum_{k = 1}^n h_k(x)(x_k - a)
\end{align}
$$