# Tangent space surjects onto space of derivations without Taylor's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Given $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let $T_a\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the tangent space at $a$ and $\mathcal{D}_a\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the space of derivations at $a$ on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

We know that there is a natural isomorphism $\varphi:T_a\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathcal{D}_a\mathbb{R}^n$ by $v\mapsto D_v|_a$. In every proof I've seen of this statement, showing that $\varphi$ is surjective involves Taylor's Theorem and looks [something like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556742/why-is-it-that-the-vector-space-of-all-derivations-has-the-basis-partial-part).

**Is there another way to show that $\varphi$ is surjective?**

Comment: It's in fact *false* if you work with $C^k$ functions for any $k\ge 1$. It's a very subtle variant of Taylor's Theorem. (With $C^k$ functions, $\mathcal D_a\Bbb R^n$ is infinite-dimensional, in fact.)

Comment: @TedShifrin But Taylor's theorem up to the $k^\text{th}$ term (with remainder) only requires $f\in C^{k+1}$, and the standard proof only requires the 2nd-order Taylor expansion (with remainder). Doesn't this contradict your comment?

Comment: @WillG I cannot read you mind. The standard proof, as I indicated, is *not* quite Taylor's Theorem with remainder, no. So you'll have to add a lot more detail to make sense of this.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was referring to the proof in App. C of "Intro to Smooth Manifolds" by John Lee (Ed. 2), Prop. 3.2. He uses a 2nd-order Taylor series with remainder, then argues that the 2nd-order remainder term vanishes when applying the derivation.

Comment: Also the answer in the linked post above is Taylor's theorem with remainder, to first order (or 0th order with 1st-order remainder), except arrived at using the fundamental theorem of calculus instead of just citing the theorem. I think this is why OP mentions Taylor's theorem with regards to that answer. It seems like a slightly modified version of Lee's proof.

Comment: Essentially my question is, why doesn't the argument in the linked post (or Lee's proof) work for $f\in C^k$ for sufficiently large but finite $k$?

Comment: I don't have Lee's book. As I've said, this is not quite a traditional Taylor expansion, if you look carefully. The usual approach is to write $f(x)=f(a)+\sum(x_i-a_i)g_i(x)$, which is (subtly) different from Taylor. As I said originally, with $C^k$ functions with $k$ finite, it gets tricky and the space of derivations is infinite-dimensional. (Note that the derivative of a $C^k$ function is no longer $C^k$.)